Debugging go in vs code
I am new to GO and previously I was using 30 days trial version of GoLand for my office work, there debugging is quite simple, Now the trial version is over and the professional subscription is expensive. I want to switch to VScode for coding and debugging purpose. In our project we have local.env file that contain configuration related to our app, in goLand it was easy to add the configuration file to start debugging. Is there any way to do it so I can add the available local.env file and debug my go code in vscode. I added launch.json but it doesn't work, a file __debug_bin is getting generated but soon is deleted.

I see two ways to go about this.

configure the envFile setting in your launch.json

incorporate environment file loading into the code itself


For the first approach you may find the VS Code documentation for Golang debugging useful, particularly the section dealing with launch.json attributes.
The latter approach makes your code independent of any particular IDE or configuration.  Configure sensible defaults in the code, where applicable, and apply environment variables by loading from a file specified in the code.
This is easy enough to build yourself, or you could use something like my own env module.  Using this you would simply incorporate code similar to the following in the startup of your project:
    if err := env.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

This will load environment variables from a .env file in the current directory.  Alternatively you can specify a different file (or files), in which case .env will still be loaded if present, but ignored if not.  An error will still be returned if any specified files are not present:
   // loads .env (if present) followed by local.env which MUST be present
   if err := env.Load("local.env"); err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }

The module also contains useful functions for converting environment variables to type-safe values and for testing.  Refer to the repo docs for more information if this sounds useful.
